# How to get a screen shot in jmonkey3

Tags: screenshot, jmonkeyengine

I am a newbie with jmonkey.
I have a simple app that i built following the jmonkey tutorials.

How can i grab a screenshot of what jmonkey is displaying. If i could select what of the nodes on the screen would be in the image that would be even better.

Answer (score 2):

There's docs on the JME3 tutorial pages:

http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3:advanced:screenshots

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this problem myself; in my case the standard print screen key worked on windowed JME3 apps, but not fullscreen. I searched & found this post, but the link @Chaotic provided seems to be dead. I was able to find the [screenshot info in the JME3 wiki](http://wiki.jmonkeyengine.org/jme3/advanced/screenshots.html) which states:

> The com.jme3.app.state.ScreenshotAppState enables your users to take screenshots of the running game.
>
> You activate this feature as follows in your simpleInitApp() method:
>
> ```
> ScreenshotAppState screenShotState = new ScreenshotAppState();
> this.stateManager.attach(screenShotState);
> ```
>
> The default screenshot key is `KeyInput.KEY_SYSRQ`, also known as “System Request / Print Screen key. On Mac keyboards, this key does not exist, so on Mac OS you take screenshots using Command+Shift+3 (fullscreen) or Command+Shift+4 (windowed: press space to select a window and then click).
>
> The screenshot is saved to the user directory.
>
> Version Last updated 2016-07-22 07:15:15 UTC